# Where is the math markdown/syntax described?

Tags: support, markdown

When I begin asking a question, no mention is made of the markdown syntax in use, or where to find its description in the quick reference, or full reference for the Math Stackexchange site in the right hand column.

Where do I find these?

Comment: You can get a description of the Markdown syntax by clicking the little orange question mark at the top right of the question box. The mathematical markup is TeX, for which some good references are mentioned in the answers to [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/934/where-is-the-latex-reference-please). Also, please post questions related to the site itself on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is now mentioned on the /ask page and in https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help as well.

Comment: it looks like it no longer is in the /ask page now? Some new users are having problems, and I don't see Math Markup mentioned [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @willie it is still there when you focus the body of the question, you get editing help including MathJax help. I agree the /editing-help should have "for further information, see..." links as well on MathJax / TeX etc.

Comment: Whoa! Dynamic JS-fu! Sorry about the noise. `:-)`